# iFrame is causing parent to scroll to iFrame position on load

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I have an iFrame that loads another iFrame inside it, when the second iFrame loads the parent scrolls to the top position of the iFrame.

iFrame 'A' is rendered on the page simply like this:

```
<iframe id="frame1" src="samedomain.com" width="745" width="100%" height="745" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

When this iFrame loads, it does not manipulate the parent windows scroll position. This iFrame is same domain.

The iFrame that this then loads, iFrame 'B' then causes the parent window to scroll to it's position. B is cross domain.

Is there a way that I can prevent the page from scrolling when the second iFrame is loaded? I am unable to alter the source code of either iFrame as this comes from a third party payment processor.

It's worth mentioning that there is no way around using multiple iFrames, to 'embed' the members area into a page on the site (rather than having a popup) we need to use an iFrame, and that members area has the iFrame with in it that is provided by a third party.

Comment: _“iFrame 'B' then causes the parent window to scroll to it's position”_ - how exactly? _“as this comes from a third party payment processor”_ - should this be happening in iframes in the first place …? Most kinds of payment processing require that the user authenticates with the payment provider somehow - and if that’s done via some sort of login form, users have no way of verifying via the address bar (because there is none, for the iframe) that they are actually entering their credentials to the payment provider, and not a phishing site …

Comment: don't do that - nest iframes

Comment: Nesting iFrames is unavoidable in this scenario. iFrame B has js that is causing the focus to go to the top of the first element in that iFrame onload. I can't alter that JS though so I was wondering if there was a way to prevent that behaviour from the outside.

Comment: you are taken two times with atribute and what is the div height with that you are taken the iframe.increase the div size may solve